# Spring boot security (embedded vs external)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, server

I know by default Spring boot produces a fat Jar file which incorporates an embedded server but when it comes down to security is there any flaws using an embedded server compare to launching your spring application to an existing server like tomcat. Is the jar or war more secure ?

Tried looking it up but I’ve seen a post explaining some pros and cons to using an embedded server vs an existing application server but I lost that post I need more insight please help. I know using embedded is quick and less work on configuration but is it more secure to deploying to an existing tomcat server or jboss instead of using spring default embedded server please help me so I don’t make mistakes when making a large app

Comment: I think this topic is overthought. Of course, everything can contain some bugs, but you have to decide your priority. What is effective? Is it worth the money and energy to invest in the external server? What is your future project plan? Will you use microservices, and how will you implement this architecture per service?

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing the use of the same application container software at the same version, then there should be zero discernible difference with either type of deployment, provided that you are *only adjusting the same configuration parameters with each deployment method*.  For example, you can use TLS 1.3 with both the external or embedded tomcat instances.  Any other part of the configuration that you can tweak the same way in both embedded and external servers will result in the same behavior and security/vulnerability.  The only time that you would get a different result is if there are configuration parameters that you can tweak when using the external server that you cannot set when using it as an embedded web server.